# Avoiding reflection - How best can I refactor this code?

Tags: reflection, go, refactoring

I started experimenting with Go, and so far it's been a blast. I decided to make a small app which will help a friend organize information business-related information in his (small) company, and I thought I would use Go to implement it.

I haven't (exactly) run into a problem, it's more of a question, when should I consider using reflection? For example, I have 3 related types: `Company`, `Project` and `Staff`. They all have several fields in common (such as `id`,`name`) so as you can imagine, the functions that load them from the database (I'm using `MySQL`) are all very similar.

Look at `LoadCompany()`, `LoadStaff()`, and `LoadProject()` :

```
// Loads the company from the database with the given id.
func LoadCompany(id int) (Company, error) {
    db := tools.OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id = ?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }   
    var c Company 
    err = stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(&c.id, &c.FullName, &c.Name, &c.History, &c.Overview, &c.Est, &c.Phone, &c.Website, &c.Email)
    if err != nil {
        return Company{}, err 
    }   
    return c, nil 
}

// Loads the staff from the database with the given id.
func LoadStaff(id int) (Staff, error) {
    db := tools.OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id = ?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    var s Staff
    err = stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(&s.id, &s.FullName, &s.Name, &s.Email, &s.Joined, &s.Left, &s.History, &s.Phone, &s.Position)
    if err != nil {
        return Staff{}, err
    }
    return s, nil
}

// Loads the project from the database with the given id.
func LoadProject(id int) (Project, error) {
    db := tools.OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id = ?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    var p Project
    err = stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(&p.id, &p.Title, &p.Overview, &p.Value, &p.Started, &p.Finished, &p.Client, &p.Architect, &p.Status)
    if err != nil {
        return Project{}, err
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

When I wrote `LoadCompany()`, I was feeling pretty good about myself (*ahem* as a beginner/intermediate programmer) because it seemed minimal and clean. But as I wrote `LoadStaff()` and `LoadProject()`, all I was doing is copying and tweaking. I'm certain there's a better way to do this, but I'm weary of jumping into reflection, after reading [Pike's post on it](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection):

> [Reflection is] a powerful tool that should be used with care and avoided unless strictly necessary.

So my question is, should I use reflection, and if so, can you give me some pointers on the best technique for something like this? This is only the tip of the iceberg, because I feel as though the rest of the functions and methods relating to these types are all similarly repetitive (and don't get me started on the tests!).

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.

Comment: Thanks...that should solve the scanning repetition, any suggestions about the 3 functions & reflection in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
func LoadObject(sql string, id int, dest ...interface{}) error {
    db := tools.OpenDB()
    defer db.Close()
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }   
    defer stmt.Close()
    return stmt.QueryRow(id).Scan(dest)
}

// Loads the company from the database with the given id.
func LoadCompany(id int) (c Company, err error) {
    err = LoadObject("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id = ?", &c.id,
        &c.FullName, &c.Name, &c.History, &c.Overview, &c.Est, &c.Phone, &c.Website, &c.Email)
    return
}
```

Note that I haven't compiled this code, but hopefully it is good enough to give you an idea.

A few suggestions:

- Read through the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/
- create `sql.DB` instance once on program start up
- specify column order explicitly in the SQL statements (`select full_name, history, .... from companies ....`)

Comment: Yes, it was nearly perfect. All I had to do is return the row because Scan() treats dest as the first in a series of items. Thanks!